# Regex: How to parse nth match

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't get this regex to parse the nth token/match.  Matching tokens is easy, but I can't extract the exact match I need.

Regex: `(?:\w+){2}(\w+)`

Input:

```
001.002.003.004
450000.459999.1.0.1.0
```

Using `(\w+)` matches all the tokens.  works perfectly.  But I can't extract the nth (e.g. 3rd or 4th).

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the language/regex library/tool/expected results?

Comment: I need it to work with java/javascript regex syntax.

Comment: Split with `\W+`, then you will be able to access any item using `[n]`

Answer (score 1):

`(?:\w+){2}` won't work as it doesn't match the period. `\w+` matches up to the period and that's where the matching ends as nothing in your regex matches period.

Try `(?:\w+\.){N}(\w+)` where `N` is the number of groups you want to **skip**. So to capture the 3rd value, N would be `2`, to capture the 4th it would be `3` and so on.

Comment: Almost... strange, this works on regex101.com, but doesn't work in the tool i'm using (which uses java under the hood). it ends up  with 3 matches: "001.002.003", "450000.459999.1", "0.1.0".  So far I haven't found differences between regex101.com and java.

Comment: @Colin You are aware, that the first group (group 0) is always the whole string that matched. The first capture group is always group 1. See http://fiddle.re/g7k3dd and click on "Java" (even is green, you first have to click it), then see the last column in the table. There are two matches, matches 0, the whole matching string and match 1, the first capture group.

Answer (score 0):

I think this regexp should solve your problem:
`/(\w+)/g`

See https://regex101.com/r/vSqV7m/1/

If your tokens are digits only using `\d` will be even better:
`/(\d+)/g`

Comment: this matches all tokens.  I only want the nth (e.g. 3rd or 4th) returned.  I only want 1 result/match and for it to be the nth token.  tokens are not guaranteed to be digits but are words e.g. alphanum.  And the seperators may not be periods but will not be alphanums.